# Cordova/Phonegap remove focus select html

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, zepto

I'm bringing my old Cordova/Phonegap in new Cordova/Phonegap 5.1.1...I have a problem...In this app there is zepto.js for manage all tap events so when I open a page, I have a bad effect...my select html is open without tap it...Is there anybody that fix this problem?
This is my code html:

```
<script id="page" type="text/template">
    <div id="answers">
        <select id="select1" style="width: 90%">
            <option value="-1" selected="selected">Seleziona una risposta</option>
            <option value="3">Entro 5 minuti</option>
            <option value="2">Entro 6-30 minuti</option>
            <option value="1">Entro 31-60 minuti</option>
            <option value="0">Dopo 60 minuti</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</script>
```

I try to remove the focus in manually mode with but doesn't work:

```
document.getElementById("select1").blur();
```

Comment: what do you mean selec is open, do you mean it selected is showing the options?

Comment: Yes, it shows the options without touch the select...when I click on this page there is the select open...Do you have an idea for this problem?